# Extracting a common Object from two Javascript objects with same keys

Tags: javascript, vue.js, javascript-objects, merging-data

I have two Javascript objects with the same keys but the keys with some value in **obj1** are empty in **obj2** and vice versa. There can also be keys that are empty in both objects.

```
obj1 = {
 a: 1,
 b: 2,
 c: ' ',
 d: ' ',
 e: ' '
}

obj2 = {
 a: ' ',
 b: ' ',
 c: 3,
 d: 5,
 e: ' '
}
```

I want a combined object which contains the keys with values from both objects, and in case both the keys are empty it simply places it as empty

```
Expected result:

result = {
 a: 1,
 b: 2,
 c: 3,
 d: 5,
 e: ' '
}
```

I have tried using the spread operator but the second object always takes precedence over the first :> {...obj1, ...obj2}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take advantage of the `Object.keys` method and the `reduce` one to create the result object

```js
let obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: ' ',
  d: ' ',
  e: ' '
}

let obj2 = {
  a: ' ',
  b: ' ',
  c: 3,
  d: 5,
  e: ' '
}
let result = Object.keys(obj1).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  val = obj1[curr] != " " ? obj1[curr] : obj2[curr];
  return { ...acc,
    ...{
      [curr]: val
    }
  }
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to build a common combined object and then loop through each of the other objects and add in the value if not empty

```js
obj1 = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: ' ',
    d: ' ',
    e: ' '
}

obj2 = {
    a: ' ',
    b: ' ',
    c: 3,
    d: 5,
    e: ' '
}

// Combine the two to get all keys into the combined object
var combined = { ...obj1, ...obj2 };

// Set each value in the combined object to a single spaced string
for (let key in combined) {
    combined[key] = ' ';
}

// Loop through each item in obj1 and add to combined if a single spaced string
for (let key in obj1) {
    if (obj1[key] !== ' ') combined[key] = obj1[key];
}

// Loop through each item in obj2 and add to combined if a single spaced string
for (let key in obj2) {
    if (obj2[key] !== ' ') combined[key] = obj2[key];
}

console.log(combined)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj1).map(e=>([e[0], obj1[e[0]]!=' '?obj1[e[0]]:obj2[e[0]]])))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the object and spread the first and filtered object.

```js
const
    filter = o => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).filter(([, v]) => v !== ' ')),
    obj1 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: ' ', d: ' ', e: ' ' },
    obj2 = { a: ' ', b: ' ', c: 3, d: 5, e: ' ' },
    result = { ...obj1, ...filter(obj2) };

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj1 = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: ' ',
    d: ' ',
    e: ' '
}

var obj2 = {
    a: ' ',
    b: ' ',
    c: 3,
    d: 5,
    e: ' '
}

/* in case your objects are not same length */
var longObj = obj1;
var shortObj = obj2;

if(Object.keys(obj1).length < Object.keys(obj2).length) {
  longObj = obj2;
  shortObj = obj1;
}

for(let k in shortObj) {
  longObj[k] = longObj[k] !== ' ' ? longObj[k] : shortObj[k]; 
}

console.log(longObj);
```